# Customize android edit preference dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences

I am using EditPreference class in my preferences, but the dialog that appears when I Click the preference is transparent. How can I customize the components of this dialog like changing the background, size and colors.

here is the preference screen

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    >
        <EditTextPreference
            app:key="cine_loop_length"
            app:title="Maximum cine loop length"
            app:defaultValue="256"
            app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
            app:summary="Set maximum cine loop length, a value between 0-256"
            />

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:key="is_save_separate_image"
            app:title="Save separate image without measurements"
            app:defaultValue="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the dialog preference
[image]

Comment: By default it doesn't normally do that, so you might want to check your theme. By the way, SeekBarPreference is probably a better choice for usability if you're having the user pick an integer value in a range.

Comment: The theme am using works on other dialogs but not this

Comment: Yes for sure SeekBarPreference was a better choice thanks.